# Handlling link/referral interruptions from facebook (Bot Framework v4)

Tags: node.js, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

Consider this scenario:

1. So when a user clicks an m.me link with referral parameters,it redirects to a messenger bot, shows some welcome message and then asks user if they want to proceed or not through a ConfirmPrompt.
2. User didn't click either yes/no **BUT** re-clicks the link with referral parameter which would cause an error since (and I don't know how to capture this error), error is at onTurn level.

Can someone kindly, explain what happened to this kind of activity and how to handle it properly (by just restarting my whole dialog for referral parameters)

THANK YOU !!! 
PS. I use NodeJs SDK for my bot, (bot framework V4)

Edited: (thank you for asking nicely about code sample for full understanding of scenario, I'll also add some screenshots for visualization of the problem)

So this code is inside the one of waterfall stages in ReferralDialog that specifically asks for user confirmation.

```
await step.context.sendActivity("Doesn’t that sound easy?");
await step.context.sendActivity({ type: 'typing'});
return await step.prompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT, 'Now, would you like to apply?', ['yes', 'no']);
```

next stage of waterfall contains snippets codes of this:

```
if(step.result)
        {
            await step.context.sendActivity("And to protect your privacy from prying eyes, I will bring you outside of messenger to a secure East West owned chat environment");


           return await step.endDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            await step.context.sendActivity("Thank you ! If you change your mind, please click the link your referrer sent you again to re-enter the program.");
            return await step.endDialog();
        }
```

Inside the main dialog (snippets):
//through fb but with ref (has already interacted)

```
else if(channelData &&  channelData.referral && channelData.referral.ref && stepContext.context.activity.channelId === 'facebook')
    {
return await stepContext.beginDialog(REFERRAL_DIALOG, userData);}
```

So the assumption was that: if user say clicks either yes/no, there will be a message for it: (but some crazy user clicks the referral link again)

So we now have this error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D86Yt.png)

2nd and 3rd image is for what bot responds:
[Messenger prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mISGH.png)
[Messenger error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD7M1.png)

The error message, occurs in index.js has this code:
(Its preset from framework, I never change/do something on that code)

```
// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    //       application insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${ error }`);

    // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in Bot Framework Emulator
    await context.sendTraceActivity(
        'OnTurnError Trace',
        `${ error }`,
        'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error',
        'TurnError'
    );

    // Send a message to the user
    let onTurnErrorMessage = 'The bot encounted an error or bug.';
    await context.sendActivity(onTurnErrorMessage, onTurnErrorMessage, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
    onTurnErrorMessage = 'To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.';
    await context.sendActivity(onTurnErrorMessage, onTurnErrorMessage, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
    await context.sendActivity(error);
    // Clear out state
    await conversationState.delete(context);
};
```

And the only toLowerCase code of my bot can be found in CancelAndHelpDialog (Also I didn't defined but add something :

```
class CancelAndHelpDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    async onContinueDialog(innerDc) {
        const result = await this.interrupt(innerDc);
        if (result) {

            console.log("Bot was interrupted");
            return result;
        }
        return await super.onContinueDialog(innerDc);
    }

    async interrupt(innerDc) {
        console.log("Interrupt");
        let interruptData=innerDc.context.activity;
        if (interruptData && interruptData.text) {
            console.log("uhhhhhhhhhmmm" + typeof innerDc.context.activity.text);
                const text = innerDc.context.activity.text.toLowerCase();

                switch (text) {
                case 'help':
                case '?': {
                    const helpMessageText = 'Call our customer service 8888-1700 for further assistance.';
                    await innerDc.context.sendActivity(helpMessageText, helpMessageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
                    return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
                }
                case 'cancel':
                case 'quit': {
                    const cancelMessageText = 'Cancelling...';
                    await innerDc.context.sendActivity(cancelMessageText, cancelMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                    return await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's really peculiar why I all my console.log() that I added in CancelAndHelpDialog wont be shown, and more importantly (to reiterate) I don't have any other toLowerCase code except in that dialog.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Since the issue was that it becomes an error to user, I found a way to change onContinueDialog and reprompt users to reclick the link. hehe

```
async onContinueDialog(innerDc) {
        console.log("This is at oncontinue Dialog");
        console.log("\n\r This is the channel Data" + JSON.stringify(innerDc.context.activity.channelData));

        let interruptData=innerDc.context.activity;
        if(interruptData.channelData.referral && interruptData.channelData.referral.ref)
        {
            await innerDc.context.sendActivity("Sorry I didn't catch it. Kindly click the link again.");   
            return await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs();
        }
        else
        {
            const result = await this.interrupt(innerDc);
            console.log("The result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
            if (result) {

                console.log("Bot was interrupted");
                return result;
            }
            return await super.onContinueDialog(innerDc);
        }
    }
```

In that way users are forced to re-clicked the link and restart all dialogs.

Comment: What is the specific onTurnError you are getting? Also, it would be helpful if we could see the relevant pieces from code, especially the beginning of this dialog where you are getting the error and also how you are initiating the conversation from the referral link.

Comment: thanks for your kind response @billoverton, I modified the question providing code snippets and screenshots in messenger and console. thanks!

Comment: You're 100% sure you don't have `toLowerCase` anywhere else? Given this error and your `toLowerCase()` line, that would imply `innerDc.context.activity.text` does not exist. However, you are also testing that `innerDc.context.activity.text` (as `interruptData.text`) exists in your if statement. So you should not be able to get into that block and try to run `toLowerCase()` if the text attribute doesn't exist. Perhaps you can add a breakpoint right before the `toLowerCase()` statement and run in debug? If you don't hit the breakpoint and still get the error, then your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I did exactly what ur comment is about sir, I put a console.log() inside onContinueDailog (I just deleted it when I finally quit and ask for help here in stackoverflow) but it didn't print the statement that I want to print. 

To reiterate, I am 100% sure that toLowerCase isn't defined by me, that whole class is already defined when I created a bot. What's fascinating is never in my code, I called that class. I swear.

Comment: I would set a break, probably at the beginning of the interrupt function, and step through to see if you can isolate the error. That will take you through any related modules as well.

Comment: So what I did currently, kindly see edit above: (it helps for customer purposes)

Comment: FINAL Response: I launched this to MS Support and to handle this kind of interruption, they already fixed this bug and what you have to do is to update the botbuilder and botbuilder-dialogs in latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously my bot is using Bot Framework 4.7.2 where it contains the bug for Facebook channel. Upgrading to 4.8.0 will get rid of the error “TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined”.